# Up navigation using item of a navigation drawer menu

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my android app I have two activities, one is the LoginInActivity (i.e. MainActivity), and the other is the HomeActivity which is a child of the first activity and is implemented with a Navigation drawer. So in my manifest file I have:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Obvioulsy in my MainActivity I create an Intent and start the HomeActivity with `startActivity()` method.

Now I would like to use an item of the Navigation Drawer as if it were a Up Button, which means that I can navigate back into the hierarchy and log out.
Furthermore, I want to add more children to HomeActivity later, which is way I did not use `startActivityForResult()` method in MainActivity and I didn't call `finish()` in HomeActivity.

I'm wondering if it's possible to implement this thing. If so, how? Otherwise it is more advisable to let the HomeActivity (with Navigation drawer) become the Main, and that the LogIn is a drawer item (e.g. calls an LoginActivity with `startActivityForResult()`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate back by calling `onBackPressed()` in your click event.

Comment: Do you mean inside `onNavigationItemSelected()` ? I just tried but it does not work